# How do i make my submit answer continue stacking on top of each other

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am currently doing a school project and i need to stimulate a server side application. What i am substituting it with is "Local Storage" but i have an issue. I am able to have the text in my "Text box" stack on top of each other once user have submitted their question. Once they reload, the data will still be displayed. But i do not know how to stack on top of it AGAIN after they reload. Below is my testing code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>



  <body onload="display()">

    <input type="text" id="Name"></input>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="SavetoStorage()"></input>


    <p id ="hoho">

    </p>
    <script>
      var name;
      var groupOfName = ["Hello", "Chicken", "Pork","Beef"];
    function SavetoStorage() {
      var name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
      groupOfName[groupOfName.length] = name;
      var newone = groupOfName;
      document.getElementById("hoho").innerHTML = newone;
      localStorage.groupOfName = newone;

    }


    function display() {
      var groupOfName = localStorage.groupOfName;
      document.getElementById("hoho").innerHTML = groupOfName;
    }







    </script>
  </head>
  </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setItem method from localstorage. 
It uses 2 parameters:

- a key and a value

so you can do something like this:

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById("Name").value;
localStorage.setItem("name", inputValue);
```

The above code sets the key "name" and that key holds the inputValue

So now you can retrieve the value by calling another local storage method called getItem:

```
var retrieveValue = localStorage.getItem("name");
```

The above code retrieves the item, and what does that item holds? the value from the input, so now you can add it to your html as you wish

So that's the basics but as you only have 1 input the value will be getting overwrited, and LocalStorage doesn't supports arrays but there's a workaround so you can use arrays, it goes something like this:

```
//this first part converts your array to string
localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(names));

//The second part returns your item and coverts it to an array again
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be dynamically loading the `groupOfName` variable like so:

```
var tmp = localStorage.groupOfName; //this is a string
var groupOfName = Array.from(tmp); //turn it into an array
```

Hopefully this helps to point you in the right direction

Comment: I am not really sure how to apply it! Do you mind providing more directions! Thanks